# this === undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    name: "BtnCertificate",
    props: ['certificate', 'show'],
    computed: {
        general_color_style: () => {
            console.log(this);
            return `background-color: red`
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.settings = this.$store.state.settings;
    },
    data: () => ({
        settings: null,
    })
```

Почему в `computed this === undefined`?

Comment: @Grundy, Вопрос не является дубликатом, так как есть решение специфичное для библиотеки Vue (отмеченной в метках вопроса).

Comment: @yar85, конечно является дубликатом.

Comment: А, ну поняяяятно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [официальной документации Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed):

> Обратите внимание, при использовании стрелочной функции в определении вычисляемого свойства, `this` не будет указывать на экземпляр компонента, но к нему можно получить доступ из первого аргумента  функции

Соответственно:

```
computed: {
  general_color_style: vm => {
    console.log(vm);
    return `background-color: red`;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это лямбда-функция, созданная в коде в строгом режиме, который либо является top-level-кодом, либо находится в функции имеющей `undefined` в качестве `this`.